# Firebase PHP admin sdk auth permission

Tags: php, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

i am using firebase php admin sdk. I have no problem with user registration, login, update or pulling user data. But no auth permission. It gives a permission error when adding something to the realtime database. How can I give auth authentication with php sdk?

This is how I can access the user's data. But I guess there is no authentication permission

```
$users = $firebase_auth->getUser($_SESSION['firebase_uid']);
print_r($users );
```

Comment: firebase-php sdk has admin access to the database. it can write read/from anywhere unless you specificly limit it. can you share your code that gives permission error?

Comment: actually i don't get an error when i do real time data operations with php. However, when I log in with php sdk, I get an access permission error when importing, writing, updating data with javascript.

As far as I understand, I need to log in with the signInWithEmailAndPassword method so that I can write and read data with js.

Comment: When I log in with php sdk, token is returned to me, is it possible to have auth permission with the token returned in the js section?